# Automorphism of $A[t]/(t^m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $t$ an indeterminate over $A$. If $f$ is an automorphism of the ring $A[t]/(t^m)$ satisfying $f(x)\equiv x\pmod{(t)}$ for each $x\in A[t]/(t^m)$ with $m$ a positive integer, then can we deduce that $f(t)=t$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no. The condition on $f$ (that $f(x) \equiv x \pmod{t}$) is equivalent to $f$ acting as the identity on $A$, but it can do "anything" within the maximal ideal (recall that $A[t]/(t^m)$ has a decomposition $A \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m-1} t^i\cdot A$).

So, for example, if $2$ is a unit in $A$, the function defined by $f(t)=2t$ satisfies your condition, and is an isomorphism of $A[t]/(t^m)$.

Comment: Does any $g$ give an automorphism $f$ (or just homomorphism)?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No (the zero function is a counter-example). That's why I formulated it as "some $g$", not "any $g$".

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer, thank you for your answer. In the example for $m=2$ you given, the automorphism should be $f(a+bt)=a+2bt$ with 2 a unit in $A$?

Comment: Is this answer assuming $m=2$? If not, I'm lost at the first sentence.

Comment: @Marc: Thank you for your comment. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @yubin: I've edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer, the condition $f(x)\equiv x(mod\ t)$ means $f(a)=a+a_1t+\cdots+a_{m-1}t^{m-1}$ for each $a\in A$, so $f$ may does not act identically on $A$. This question is from page 207 of Matsumura's book "commutative ring theory". When $m=2$ and $f(a+bt)=a+2bt$, $f$ is a ring automorphism of $A[t]/(t^2)$ and shows the answer to my question is "no".